# Sending id value to parent component when child check box is checked

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In my angular 11 app, I have multiple components that each display a modal ( parent component ) that displays multiple components ( child component ) called `FileInfo` and has a button called "save" and another to close the modal I added a check box to each of the components, I want to send the `fileId` to the parent component when a check box is checked and the button "save" is clicked ( only one file can be checked ), the idea is the user will check a file from a modal and check another file form another modal and both `fileIds` will be sent to the other component that calls an API endpoint which takes two ids in parameter to compare the two files.

I managed to display the `fileId` when a file box is checked on an open modal and store it in the array where I planned to keep the `fileIds` but when I switched to another modal and checked another file the array got overwritten.

How do I fix that, and is there a better way to implement something like this?

Here is the code I used :

file-info.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-file-info',
  templateUrl: './file-info.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./file-info.component.scss'],
})
export class FileInfoComponent implements OnInit {
  faFileCsv = faFileCsv;
  faTrash = faTrash;
  faFileDownload = faFileDownload;
  selectedFiles: any[] = [];
  @Output()
  public myOutput = new EventEmitter<any>();
  @Input() fileInfo: {
    _id: string;
    fileName: string;
    createdAt: string;
    NumberRecords: string;
  };
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  public handleClick(_id: string): void {
    this.myOutput.emit(this.fileInfo._id);
  }
  saveedFiles() {}
  check(e) {
    //console.log(e);
    //console.log(e.target.checked);
    this.selectedFiles.push(e.target.value);
    console.log(this.selectedFiles);
  }
}
```

file-info.component.html

```
<div class="card files EqualHeightCard">
  <div class="card-content">
    <div class="columns">
      <input
        (change)="check($event)"
        name="fileId"
        value="{{ fileInfo._id }}"
        type="checkbox"
      />
      <div class="column is-2 forImg">
        <fa-icon [icon]="faFileCsv" size="4x"></fa-icon>
      </div>
      <div class="column forInfos">
        <p class="SourceName">File Name : {{ fileInfo.fileName }}</p>
        <p class="SourceDesc mt-2">
          Number of records : {{ fileInfo.NumberRecords }}
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="column forInfos">
        <p class="SourceName">Loading date : {{ fileInfo.createdAt }}</p>
      </div>

      <div class="buttons">
        <div class="ml-4">
          <fa-icon [icon]="faFileDownload" size="2x"></fa-icon>
        </div>
        <div class="ml-4">
          <fa-icon
            [icon]="faTrash"
            size="2x"
            (click)="handleClick($event)"
          ></fa-icon>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br />
```

modal.component.html

```
<div class="centered-content">
  <div class="modal is-active">
    <div class="modal-background"></div>
    <div class="modal-card">
      <header class="modal-card-head">
        <p class="modal-card-title">{{ sourceName }} uploaded files history</p>
      </header>
      <section class="modal-card-body">
        <app-file-info
          *ngFor="let fileInfo of FileInfoList"
          [fileInfo]="fileInfo"
          (myOutput)="parentHandleClick($event)"
        ></app-file-info>
        <p>Number of files : {{ FileInfoList.length }}</p>
      </section>
      <footer class="modal-card-foot">
        <div class="buttons is-right">
          <button class="button is-success">Save changes</button>
          <button
            class="button is-danger is-outlined"
            aria-label="close"
            (click)="cancel()"
          >
            <span>Close</span>
            <span class="icon is-small">
              <fa-icon [icon]="faTimes"></fa-icon>
            </span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

modal.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal',
  templateUrl: './modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./modal.component.scss'],
})
export class ModalComponent implements OnInit {
  faFileCsv = faFileCsv;
  faTimes = faTimes;
  FileInfoList: any = [];
  @Input() sourceId: { _id: string };
  @Input() sourceName: { name: string };
  constructor(private readonly _crudService: CrudService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    /*  this._crudService.GetFileInfoList().subscribe((res) => {
      this.FileInfoList = res;
    }); */
    this._crudService.GetALLFilesOfSource(this.sourceId).subscribe((res) => {
      this.FileInfoList = res;
    });
  }
  @Output()
  onClose = new EventEmitter();
  cancel() {
    this.onClose.emit(null);
  }
  parentHandleClick($event) {
    return this._crudService
      .DeleteFileOfSource(this.sourceId, $event)
      .subscribe((res) => {
        this.FileInfoList = res;
      });
  }
}
```

crud.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { catchError, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import {
  HttpClient,
  HttpHeaders,
  HttpErrorResponse,
} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class CrudService {
  // Node/Express API
  REST_API: string = 'http://localhost:4000';
  // Http Header
  httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  // Get all objects
  GetTransactions() {
    return this.httpClient.get(`${this.REST_API}/trans-list`);
  }
  GetMatchingTransactions() {
    return this.httpClient.get(`${this.REST_API}/trans-match`);
  }
  GetGeneratedMatchingFile() {
    return this.httpClient.get(`${this.REST_API}/trans-match-file`);
  }
  /**
   * GET /files-list
   * Purpose: Get all sheets ( files)
   */
  GetFileInfoList() {
    return this.httpClient.get(`${this.REST_API}/files-list`);
  }
  GetALLDataSources() {
    return this.httpClient.get(`${this.REST_API}/source`);
  }
  /**
   * GET /sources/:sourceId/sheets
   * Purpose: Get all sheets in a specific data source
   */
  GetALLFilesOfSource(sourceId: any) {
    return this.httpClient.get(`${this.REST_API}/sources/${sourceId}/sheets`);
  }
  /**
   * Delete /sources/:sourceId/sheets/:sheetId
   * Purpose: Delete specific file of a  data source
   */
  DeleteFileOfSource(sourceId: any, sheetId: any) {
    return this.httpClient.delete(
      `${this.REST_API}/sources/${sourceId}/sheets/${sheetId}`
    );
  }
  GetReportsHistory() {
    return this.httpClient.get(`${this.REST_API}/reports`);
  }
  // Error
  handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    let errorMessage = '';
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      // Handle client error
      errorMessage = error.error.message;
    } else {
      // Handle server error
      errorMessage = `Error Code: ${error.status}\nMessage: ${error.message}`;
    }
    console.log(errorMessage);
    return throwError(errorMessage);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the entire code of crud service?

Comment: Hey @GabrielSereno, yes ofc please check my updated question with the added code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your modal component gets destoryed after closing it. So the component properties are lost.
You could implement a service that is able to save your file infos temporarily and handle all of your requests.

For example:

```js
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ModalService {

    fileInfoList: FileInfo[] = [];
    selectedFiles: FileInfo[] = [];

    constructor(private readonly _crudService: CrudService) { }

    loadDataSource(sourceId: string) {
        this._crudService.GetALLFilesOfSource(sourceId).subscribe((res) => {
            this.fileInfoList = res;
        });
    }

    check(id: string) {
        // checked file gets added to an array
        const file = this.fileInfoList.find(x => x._id === id);
        if (file != null) {
            this.selectedFiles.push(file);
        }
    }

    compare() {
        // call endpoint after save
        this._crudService.compareFiles(this.selectedFiles.map(x => x._id)).subscribe((res) => {
            console.log(res);
        })
    }

}

interface FileInfo {
    _id: string;
    fileName: string;
    createdAt: string;
    NumberRecords: string;
}
```

So each modal can inject this service and is able read the files that were selected from a previous modal.

Comment: Hey @marjay thank you for your response, do you mind elaborating on how the modal service will be called on the modal component, I am having trouble figuring out how to subscribe to `loadDataSource` which is already a subscription...

Comment: The subscription is already handled in the modal service as shown in my example. You just have to call the `loadDataSource` method from the `ngOnInit` of your modal component.

Comment: i call the `loadDataSource` method like this `this._modalService.loadDataSource(this.sourceId)` ? i console.log this and it returns undefined i added a return to `loadDataSource`and now it returns a subscription...

Comment: the data from the request is saved in `fileInfoList` inside the service. there are two options now: 1. you remove the `.subscribe` inside the `loadDataSource`, return the Observable and subscribe to it from your modal component. Or 2. you replace `FileInfoList: any = [];` in your modal component with `get FileInfoList() { return this._modalService.fileInfoList; }`

Comment: Thank you @marjay that works for `loadDataSource` as for the check function I tried to emit an event from on check from the `FileInfo` component and receive the emitted id on the modal component where I call  `this._modalService.check($event) and console.loged the `selectedFiles` array but its empty..

Comment: which option did you choose? its hard to help without seeing the current state. maybe the id parameter of your `check` function is null. do more logging or debug through every method to see step by step whats going on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231933/discussion-between-souhail-and-marjay).